# How can I run an EXE program from a Windows Service On Windows 10 using C#?

Tags: process, windows-services, windows-10

I am trying to execute my program via windows service over #Windows 10# (LocalSystem Account). The program has Windows Forms UI (c#), it cannot run.
The one idea i came with is to run it as a tray-bar standard program , do you have any other solutions?

### Here's my code:

```
ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo(location);
    proc.UseShellExecute = false;
    proc.RedirectStandardError = true;
    proc.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    proc.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    proc.CreateNoWindow = true;
    proc.ErrorDialog = false;
    proc.UseShellExecute = false;
    proc.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    Process process = Process.Start(proc);
```

Comment: Hi GhostCat , this is known issue for pro windows platform developers. even a minimal code is not required for the question.

Comment: Ah, sorry, misread your question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't running an executable. The problem is that services simply do not run in a user's desktop environment. Even the "tray bar" is part of that desktop, so that's no solution either.

The solution is to let the user start your program, and have it connect via IPC to your service.